# Must Interval Graph be connected always?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

We know that :

Formally, an interval graph is a type of intersection graphs of a family of intervals .Moreover, it has one vertex for each interval in the set, and an link/edge between every pair of vertices corresponding to intervals that intersect.

But the question is : Can the interval graph be disconnected or it must be connected always?

Please see the picture :
 if it is Interval or not?

http://s13.postimg.org/u320a7scn/Screenshot_3.jpg

Comment: hhaa, w.t.f very simple question, no one can answer :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for an interval graph to be a connected graph. The formal definition of an interval graph, along with the way it is constructed, does not require connectedness.

[Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0700251X) is an example of a paper which discusses disconnected interval graphs (emphasis mine):

> Bodlaender provides a proof for the NP-completeness of the
>   pair-complete coloring problem for **disconnected cographs and interval
>   graphs** and extends his results for connected such graphs. His proof
>   also establishes the NP-hardness of the harmonious coloring problem
>   for **disconnected interval graphs** and cographs. [...] On the contrary,
>   although the harmonious coloring problem is NP-complete for
>   **disconnected interval graphs**, the complexity of the problem for connected interval graphs is not straightforward. [...]
>
> -Asdre, Ionnidou an Nikolopoulos, *The harmonious coloring problem is NP-complete for interval and permutation graphs*, ScienceDirect.